# How to extend a Linux ext3 partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, ext3

I have the following partitions on my HDD:

[image: partitions]

I want to extend my Linux partition `/dev/sda6` with the unallocated space of ~1GB above it.

But when I right click on this partition the option to „resize/move” is not available. What should I do in order to obtain what I want?

Comment: Is the resize/move option available for /dev/sda5?

Comment: @shufler yes, that's how I got that unallocated space, i resized /dev/sda5

Comment: Is /dev/sda6 currently mounted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GParted cannot move or resize a partition if it's mounted and in use. It looks like you may be  attempting to move the root partition for the currently running system you will need to use a GParted Live CD.

See [Acquiring GParted on Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-acquire-livecd). Once you've booted with the Live CD you should be able to move and resize this partition.

Comment: Right now I have /dev/sda6 unmounted (I'm not in linux anymore) and I still cannot move/resize it.

Comment: Hmm... where are you running GParted from if not from Linux?

Comment: Considering the fact that I didn't have gparted on live cd (I don't have blank cds also), I booted in windows and tried to move the partition using another partitioning program (easeus). But, as I said, it doesn't let me do that. I don't know what's causing this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I finally booted using GParted live CD and the option to move or resize `/dev/sda6` was available. So I did this and the operation was successful. Thank you!